# numpy array assigning values

Tags: numpy, python-2.7

technically what is the difference between

```
import numpy as np
a = np.random.random((100,3))
b = numpy.empty((100))

# what the difference between
b = a[:,0]
# and
b[:] = a[:,0]
```

The reason I am asking that I am reading b with a fortran compiled function and the slicing in b is making all the difference. This has something to do with the column and row reading style between C and fortran. In default numpy convention is the C one.

Answer (score 3):

The main difference is that

```
b = a[:,0]
```

creates a view onto `a`'s data, whereas

```
b[:] = a[:,0]
```

makes a copy of the data.

The former uses the same memory layout as `a`, whereas the latter preserves the memory layout of the original `b`. In particular  this means that in the latter case all the data gets compacted into consecutive memory locations:

```
In [29]: b = numpy.empty((100))

In [30]: b = a[:,0]

In [31]: b.strides
Out[31]: (24,)



In [32]: b = numpy.empty((100))

In [33]: b[:] = a[:,0]

In [34]: b.strides
Out[34]: (8,)
```

Comment: As a side note to NPE's answer, in the first case, the `numpy.empty((100))` array is discarded, because `b` no longer points to it.